# Activate FileStream on SQL Server 2012 only with code (query)

Tags: sql-server-2012, filestream

I'm desperately trying to activate FileStream only with queries. By following the MSDN procedure everything is ok, but I would like to enable it without using SQL Server Configuration Manager or SQL Server Management Studio.

On several website I read that this query was enough to activate this feature (this query is done in the MSDN procedure but after some configuration in SQL Server Configuration Manager ) :

```
EXEC sp_configure 'filestream_access_level', 2;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

The message `L` option de configuration `filestream access level` est passée de 2 à 2. Pour installer, exécutez l'instruction RECONFIGURE." is gave but if I check the service's proprieties Filestream is steal disabled, even if I execute RECONFIGURE again. If I try to open a connection to a base featuring Filestream columns i get a message confirming Filestream is not enabled.

I also tried this query :

```
USE master
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options'
GO
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 3
GO
EXEC sp_filestream_configure 
@enable_level = 3
, @share_name = N'FS';
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Without succes, althougth the sp_filestream_configure seems to not exist.

This website tell the issue could be the default language of my server, but after change the default language to English nothing was better.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1...tream-access-l

I hope someone will be able to help me. Thanks. Sorry for my bad english, I'm french ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do both. One is enabling the feature in the configuration manager. The other is setting the access level.

Here's the MSDN guide to walk through:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx

You're only doing step 11, you need to do the first 10 steps as well.

Comment: Yes, but is it a way to do it without using the configuration manager ?

Comment: Hayden Hancock [gives you the steps](https://haydenhancock.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/enable-filestream-via-powershell/)  to enable it through Powershell, so I'll just link to that article for you.